# Error getting controller list

Tags: ros, ros-control, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I attempt to get the list of controllers from the controller_manager in Kinetic, I get an error:

```
> rosrun controller_manager controller_manager list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/controller_manager/controller_manager", line 41, in <module>
    controller_manager_interface.list_controllers()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/controller_manager/controller_manager_interface.py", line 60, in list_controllers
    print '%s - %s ( %s )'%(c.name, c.hardware_interface, c.state)
AttributeError: 'ControllerState' object has no attribute 'hardware_interface'
```

My knowledge of python is pretty shaky, but it looks like hardware_interface is not a member of c, but rather of c.claimed_resources. Anybody else seeing this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269757/error-getting-controller-list/) by [Ian Gough](https://answers.ros.org/users/30852/ian-gough/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gkuehner](https://answers.ros.org/users/32043/gkuehner/) on 2017-09-27**:
I've come across it while attempting to troubleshoot another problem. Make any headway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the same problem.  It looks like it's been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/commit/bd5a208632fb9a7bf637223ea6d8e07d3469a15d#diff-790b62616a777301abf4e8d8657c9142).

---

Originally posted by [zultron](https://answers.ros.org/users/34470/zultron/) with karma: 51 on 2018-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0